# mozilla space between rotated div and his shadow

Tags: html, css

I have a space between my div and his shadow only on mozilla.

HTML

```
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
transform: rotate(10deg);
position: absolute;
}
.box1 {
background-color: #444444;
z-index: 2;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.box2 {
background-color: crimson;
z-index: 1;
top: 100px;
left: 100px;
}
```

How can i fix it please.

thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/hL3e16mh/ <-- mozilla

Answer (score 0):

`box-shadow` is not the cause of your issue, It's `transform: rotate(10deg);` which is not render properly on Mozilla. So you can go with alternate solution like this:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  position: absolute;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: #444444;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  border: 10px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
}
.box2 {
  background-color: crimson;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

You can also check this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kzdLsbjw/) Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the 10px shadow was to show the problem. i found a solution with  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,1));